# After invoking char* var (assume global access) = fgets(..) inside a function, the value inside var changes unexpectedly after function call from main

Tags: c, string, io, fgets, stdio

**[Edit: Apperently the return value obtained from fgets is simply the address of the char buffer[SIZE] being used, so in my case it makes sense because I declared it locally (hence, block scope).. PS: Thanks for all the help!]**

I just leant that the data stored by fgets doesn't stay the same once the compiler is done executing the function in which fgets is being invoked.

**What's the reason behind this? Does the fgets' return data have a lifespan or something? If so, how did they even code a function such as fgets? Something that can keep track of the user's invocation scope?**

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

void input_string (char** pptr_one, char** pptr_two)
{
    char buffer[SIZE];
    printf("\nInput: ");
    char* x = fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    
    //Copying the original fgets result address:
    *pptr_one = x;
    //Copying its contents to another variable:
    *pptr_two = malloc(SIZE);
    strcpy(*pptr_two, x);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* ptr_one;
    char* ptr_two;
    input_string(&ptr_one, &ptr_two);

    printf("\nptr_one is pointing to: <%s>\n", ptr_one);
    printf("ptr_two is pointing to: <%s>\n", ptr_two);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To put it another way, you passed the address of a "local variable" to `fgets()`, and we all hope it did its job and filled in that buffer for you. When your function returned, the "local storage" evaporated... It's not a good idea to hang on to the address of local variables after a function exits... You could always find out about declaring "buffer" to be "static"... Give that a look-in...

Comment: Re “hence, function scope”: Only `goto` labels have function scope. Identifiers declared inside the body of a function have block scope.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Gotcha, thanks. I'll re-edit the post. I didn't know the exact term..

Answer (score 4):

Your buffer `char buffer[SIZE]` has automatic storage duration.

This means that after the function `input_string()` returns, the memory associated with `buffer` is freed and `buffer` will cease to exist since it is a local variable.

Solution:

You could allocate memory for `buffer` with `malloc()`:

- `char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE)`

Or you could declare `buffer` as `static`:

- `static char buffer[SIZE];`

Answer (score 2):

You (indirectly) set `*pptr_one` to the address of `buffer`, which stops existing when `input_string` ends.

There's nothing special about `fgets`; it just returns its first argument on success, which in this case is `buffer`; afterwards, `x` and `*pptr_one` all point to the same piece of memory which is local to your function.

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: Ohhh, wait so that's what it is! So, it's essentially returning someting pointing to address of the previously declared char buffer array? Wait, so whats the whole point of even obtaining a return value from fgets when you can simply access the char buffer array that you just created? Thanks by the way.

Comment: `fgets` returns its first argument _on success_ or a null pointer on failure; the return value lets you check whether it succeeded or failed (and you should check). Why the first argument and not `(char *)1` or something else non-null? Hard to say, but it can be convenient sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
void input_string (char** pptr_one, char** pptr_two)
{
    char buffer[SIZE];
    printf("\nInput: ");
    char* x = fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    // missing test for NULL return from fgets()

    /*** DO NOT DO THIS.
     * DO NOT TAKE THE ADDRESS OF A LOCAL VARIABLE FOR USE AFTER FUNCTION EXITS!
     * When successful, fgets will return the address of 'buffer' so x points to buffer.
    //Copying the original fgets result address:
    *pptr_one = x;
    *****/

    //Copying its contents to another variable:
    *pptr_two = malloc(SIZE);
    // should check that malloc succeeded
    strcpy(*pptr_two, x);
    // Aren't you glad that fgets() guarantees buffer will be a null terminated string?

    // Be sure caller free's the allocated piece of heap storage!
}
```

Or, if you want to use that info, make buffer static...

```
    static char buffer[SIZE];
    printf("\nInput: ");
```

Do NOT free the address if using a static block of memory.

Reviewing the OP, you wrote this: "I just learnt that the data stored by fgets `doesn't stay the same once the ... [execution of] the function in which fgets is being invoked.`"

All data has a duration. Some is the duration of a file on disk, some is the entire duration of a program's execution, some is the fleeting duration of a function call.

Your 'buffer' evaporated when `input_string()` ended and returned to its calling function ('main()'). Another way to hang onto the data is to define it in `main()` and pass the buffer AND its length to `input_string()`.

```
void input_string( char *buf, size_t len ) {
    fgets(buffer, len, stdin);
}

int main() {
    char buffer[ SIZE ];
    input_string( buffer, sizeof buffer );
    printf( "Got '%s' from stdin\n", buffer );
}
```

Above, `input_string()` finished, but the data was still available.

Comment: @SaiSurisetti: Avoid using `static` this way. Such a static object prevents the function from being used in multiple threads, since the different threads might attempt to use the static object at the same time. Or a single thread might want to hold two or more results from the function simultaneously. You should learn the proper techniques for dynamically allocating memory.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, I just realized this, if we use static in this scenario, we'd end up loosing the previous input reads. I think strcpy or allocating buffer in the main is practical.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course, "embedded systems" often prohibit the use of dynamic allocation... There's all sorts of ways and means and requirements... `:-)`